# Print stacktrace in my Visual Studio C++ program if a segmentation fault occurs

Tags: c++, windows, segmentation-fault, signals

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 at my workplace. I have a C++ project, and I would like to print the stacktrace into my logfile if the program crashes. I can print stacktrace in any point of the code using the Debug Help Library.
So I use the classic signal function in order to catch SIGSEGV and other signals. I wrote a "wrong" code to crash my program. My signal handler is called, and I tried to print the stacktrace.
If the code that creates the problem is in the main -> foo1 -> foo2 -> foo3 function, I expect that the stacktrace will show something like this:

signalHandler

foo3

foo2

foo1

main

But I got this stacktrace:

ucrtbase.dll: : _seh_filter_exe (0)

myProgram.exe: D:\a_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:
__scrt_common_main_seh (304)

VCRUNTIME140.dll: : _seh_longjmp_unwind4 (0)

KERNEL32.DLL: : BaseThreadInitThunk (0)

ntdll.dll: : RtlGetFullPathName_UEx (0)

ntdll.dll: : RtlGetFullPathName_UEx (0)

I think when my program crashes, the system calls my signal handler function, with an OTHER stack... How can I catch this error such a way that I want to print the correct stacktrace?

Edit:
Here is my code:
`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "dbg.h"
#include "demo.h"

#include <csignal>

void mySignalHandler(int sigint) {
    std::cout << "signal handler: " << sigint;
    test();
    exit(1);
}

void Func5() {
    std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    int* a = nullptr;
    *a = 666;
    std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    //test();
}

void Func4() { Func5(); }

void Func3() { Func4(); }

void Func2() { Func3(); }

void Func1() { Func2(); }

int main()
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, mySignalHandler);
    Func1();
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

`
If I uncomment the //test() line and comment *a = 666, I get the correct stacktrace (Func5 -> Func4 -> Func3 .... etc). If I let the code like this, I got the wrong stacktrace. It seems like an other process calls the mySignalHandler function, and because of this, it prints an other stacktrace.

Comment: Can't you try to generate a crash dump to see the stacktrace?

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger first? You can both debug at runtime or from a crash dump. For built in stacktracing you will have to wait for C++23 (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stacktrace).

Comment: Probably you are calling RtlGetFullPathName with an unitialized pointer, incorrect string (not null terminated), or a pointer to a buffer that's too small. But hard to say from this little info.

Comment: I want to implement this function in order to if I get a log file from the users, I can easily investigate where is the problem.

Comment: I dont call RtlGetFullPathName function, I think the system does it.